# Undefined reference when trying to link libxc to fortran

Tags: compilation, fortran, static-linking, lib

I am trying to compile a simple fortran program that uses libxc.

```
PROGRAM example_basicF90

   USE xc_f90_lib_m ! XCs, types and functions

   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTEGER :: i, vmajor, vminor, vmicro

   CALL xc_f90_version(vmajor, vminor, vmicro)
   WRITE(*,100) vmajor, vminor, vmicro

100 FORMAT("Libxc version: ",I1,"."I1"."I1)

END PROGRAM
```

I have compiled libxc using gcc/9.2.0 following the instructions provided on the git repo Without any issues

```
./configure --prefix=/scratch/Applications/libxc/libxc-6.0.0/GCC
make
make check 
make install
```

The issue I encounter is when I try to compile the simple code.

```
export LD_LIBXC=/scratch/Applications/libxc/libxc-6.0.0/GCC
gfortran -o example_basic -L${LD_LIBXC}/lib -lxcf90 -lxc -I${LD_LIBXC}/include example_basic.f90

example_basic.f90:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `__xc_f90_lib_m_MOD_xc_f90_version'
```

I double checked the lib and include directories for the correct files, and everything seems appropriate:

```
ls ${LD_LIBXC}/lib
libxc.a  libxcf03.a  libxcf03.la  libxcf90.a  libxcf90.la  libxc.la  pkgconfig

$ ls ${LD_LIBXC}/include
libxc.bib  xc_f03_lib_m.mod  xc_f90_lib_m.mod  xc_funcs.h  xc_funcs_removed.h  xc_funcs_worker.h  xc.h  xc_version.h
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which library do you think contains `__xc_f90_lib_m_MOD_xc_f90_version` and have you checked that it does?

Comment: Hi, @francescalus thanks... so `__xc_f90_lib_m_MOD_xc_f90_version` should be inside `libxcf90.a`. I able able to locate the subroutine `xc_f90_version` under `${LD_LIBXC}/src/libxcf90.f90` which should also produce the module file `xc_f90_lib_m`

Comment: And you've confirmed that `__xc_f90_lib_m_MOD_xc_f90_version` is defined in `${LD_LIBXC}/lib/libxcf90.a`?

Comment: Yes, a look at the external symbols shows that it is there:
```$ nm -g libxcf90.a | grep version
00000000000023e0 T __xc_f90_lib_m_MOD_xc_f90_version
00000000000020f0 T __xc_f90_lib_m_MOD_xc_f90_version_string
                 U xc_version
                 U xc_version_string```

Comment: In which case you may simply need to ensure that `example_basic.f90` is given to the compiler/linked earlier in the command line than the library itself. As in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14978800/3157076).

Comment: @francescalus this has fixed the issue I was experiencing. Thanks for your help!